# How to apply style on primefaces selectManyCheckbox->selectItems->label?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, styles

I have a primefaces selectManyCheckbox element with dynamic content:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox
    id="mySelectManyCheckbox"
    value="#{myView.mySelectManyCheckboxValue}"
    layout="responsive"
    columns="1"
>
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{myView.myCollectionOfCheckBoxes}"
        var="singleCheckbox"
        itemLabel="#{singleCheckbox.description}"
        itemValue="#{singleCheckbox.id}"
    />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I face a css issue, when the label is too long, it goes underneath the checkbox element.

[image]

Is there any approach to show label right to the checkbox and break? something like this to better understand:

[image]

Comment: You can also try this solution which sounds exactly like your problem: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=50771

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Label does not align when using long text on a p:selectOneRadio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104787/label-does-not-align-when-using-long-text-on-a-pselectoneradio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers) I was able to try a solution that fit to my issue. I guess the right solution depends on the rest of the styles coming from various css.

Anyway for me worked:

```
body .ui-selectmanycheckbox label {
    margin-top: -22px !important;
    display: block !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```

The link above was very exhaustive, I suggest to try some combinations of those solutions to anybody has similar problems.

Comment: Did you try the link provided by @WoAiNii on the question... looks like that is less dependent on default paddings etc...

Answer (score -1):

You can also apply style to td to avoid that margin and padding adjusments

```
    .ui-selectmanycheckbox.ui-widget td, .ui-selectoneradio.ui-widget td {
    border: 0 none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```